# Prominent Python projects using Nose for testing

Tags: python, testing, nose

What are some well-known Python projects that use Nose for testing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org) and [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/), for instance.